# Class 'App\Carbon\Carbon' not found Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I recently **run** `sudo composer update`

Now on one of my pages, I kept getting

[image]

I did use

`$now = Carbon\Carbon::now('America/New_York');`

in line `792` on my `Helper.php`

My **Helper.php** located at `app/Helper.php`

How do I prevent this ?

---

This is what I have in my aliases

```
'aliases' => [

    'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Bus'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Input'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
    'Inspiring' => Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring::class,
    'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

    /*
     * Extra Alias ...
     */

    'Form'        => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
    'Html'        => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',

    /*
     * Custom ...
     */

    'VSE'         => App\VSE::class,
    'Helper'      => App\Helper::class,
    'DateHelper'  => App\Helpers\DateHelper::class,
    'DD'          => App\Helpers\DD::class,
    'Facebook'    => SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\FacebookFacade::class,


],
```

---

Comment: do you use 'use Carbon' in your controller?.

Comment: add `use Carbon;` on top of my controller fix the issue :D

Comment: But I don't have to do that before running `sudo composer update`. I guess, I'll add `use Carbon;` from now on.

Comment: no matter to composer update

Comment: What you mean by no matter ???

Comment: i mean after write use carbon no need to update composer for reflect the result

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the context of the helpers file, I believe `Carbon\Carbon` = `App\Carbon\Carbon`

Whereas `\Carbon\Carbon` would be pulling in what you want!

Using the `\` at the beginning refers to a sort of global namespace.

Answer (score 5):

Use Carbon:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Answer (score 2):

After going through this, i found a way out, it might help someone there.

In laravel go to app.php, go to aliases and add 'Carbon' => 'Carbon\Carbon'. 
Then use this in blade to format it e.g.

```
<span>{{  Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($message->created_at))->diffForHumans()}}</span>
```

.Done.

Answer (score 0):

```
//laravel 5.6
//In your Controller

use Carbon\Carbon;

//ex. function
public function store(Request $request)
   { 

    $borrow = new Borrow;
    $borrow->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $borrow->book_id = $request->input('book_id');
    $borrow->borrowtime = Carbon::today();  //This uses the class Carbon
    $borrow->returntime = "-----------";
    $borrow->save();

    return redirect('student/Categories/Thesis/showtt');
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

If You are Using larave 5.7.*

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
```

**In Model or Controller Where You want**

Answer (score 0):

In the `helper.php` file, use `Carbon` class like this.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Answer (score -1):

use Carbon\Carbon in AuthserviceProviders

Comment: You are answering a 1 year old question. It must help other reader with sames problems ans thus be longer then 6 words and more precise