# Carbon\Carbon not found inconsistently - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, php-carbon

So currently I pull back a date and convert it to a readable format in carbon:

```
</div>
<div class="">
 <label for="Name">Letter Sent:</label>
 @if (is_null($Client->letter_posted))
 @else
   {{  \carbon\carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$Client->letter_posted)->format('d/m/Y')}}
 @endif
</div>
```

And it works when testing  (Testing both whilst letter_posted is null and not) however very occasionally it will spit out the error on the live server:

```
Class 'carbon\carbon' not found
```

It has only occurred 3 times in the last 2 months very randomly and a refresh of the page will remove this error eg. the error appears, if you refresh the page it is no longer there.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
{{  \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$Client->letter_posted)->format('d/m/Y')}}
```

This happens when you deploy the system in a case sensitive server.

Comment: Surely if that was the problem it would error out every time?

Comment: It is also better that you move that logic to the controller, you should not do that in a view.

Comment: If you are developing using Windows, for example, but you deploy your app in a Linux machine, this will probably happen just when you deploy.

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't happen on the live server as well. At least 99% of the time. This site is used every day by people however this error pops up in different clients every 2 weeks or so.

Comment: I understand, but you should take in consideration this case-sensitive issue. This is certainly an actual problem and can cause future issues as well. You should consider following PHP good practices to avoid this kind of issue. This is not official, but can help you, take a look: https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices

Comment: 100% I am taking this into consideration and will definitely use this practice in the future however is there anything else which could actually cause this error as to me anything else seems incredibly illogical?

Comment: Unfortunately, In the code you've posted, I can only see this as a potential problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are receiving the error because you're using `carbon\carbon` somewhere in your code instead of `\carbon\carbon`.

Putting the `\` in front refers to the global namespace. Without the `\`, you are referring to a class that might not exist (which is the error you are getting).

See: [Class 'App\Carbon\Carbon' not found Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902831/class-app-carbon-carbon-not-found-laravel-5)

---

You can create an alias to avoid using the full name in Laravel. In `app.php`, go to aliases and add `'Carbon' => 'Carbon\Carbon'`. You can then use it like this:
`{{ Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $Client->letter_posted)->format('d/m/Y') }}`

---

Additional note: while PHP namespaces are not case-sensitive, it is good practice to treat them as case-sensitive: use `\Carbon\Carbon` instead of `\carbon\carbon`.